# How to let visitors wait until a method is finished in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website and when it starts up it can take up to 20 seconds until it is ready. The startup is done off course by a visitor. But it is possible that another visitor comes when the site is starting up. In this case I want the visitor to wait until my method (which is invoked by the first visitor) is finished. Then he/she may proceed to the Home page.

How can I do this? Let every visitor wait until my method is finished loading?

EDIT: The method which can take a while is invoked from my global.asax

Comment: How are you deploying?

Comment: I publish my site using Visual Studio and copy paste the files to the server and overwrite those files.

Comment: Use Global.Asax, create two static booleans, set the first boolean to true when the first visitor enters, set the second boolean to true when the startup is finished. So, when an user enters, the Load method should check for the first boolean, if it's false do startup, if it's true check the second, if it's false redirect to an static page with "site is loading, please try again in some seconds" else load the page

Comment: Thanks, but how do I perform a redirect in my global.asax?

Answer (score 2):

Just store a simple boolean flag somewhere: in a static field, database, cache and whenever second user tries to access the website, you check if flag was set and if it was, you do what you want with that user. Even this dirty hack is fine:

```
while (ShouldWait())
{
    // Wait 5 seconds and check again
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

---

Here is a working example:

```
public class StartupFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static bool isReady = false;
    private static bool isStartingUp = false;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (isReady) return;

        if (!isStartingUp) 
        {
            isStartingUp = true;
            DoLongRunningOperation();
            isReady = true;
            return;
        } 

        while (!isReady) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    private void DoLongRunningOperation() 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
}
```

And you need to register it globally:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new StartupFilterAttribute());
}
```

Ideally this needs to be rewritten using async/await keywords.